# TFS Registry Editor needed

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is there a tool available to edit TFS registry akin to the registry editor tool for the windows registry? I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I've done it in the database before, it's a bit scary if you don't know what you're doing, and MS will not support you, should you mess it up :)

Comment: I can understand and I want to avoid going that route for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

See this commandline tool http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/02/01/change-notification-delay-setting-in-tfs-2010.aspx, but it only supports 2010-2013, so you might need to use a binding redirect to the newer DLLs if you down't have an older version of the TFS OM installed on your machine

Comment: That's what I'm currently using right now and it does work with TFS 2015. Though, I'm interested in a GUI based tool, if available.